# Adding properties to cq5 folder outside of CRXDE? or a method of using CRXDE with GIT effectively?

Tags: aem

How do I add properties to cq5 folders (nodes) outside of CRXDE, so I can create an entire CQ project in eclipse. The reason behind attempting to achieve this is I am having issues with GIT and working inside of CRXDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options for using version control in conjunciton with CRX would be…

1. Using [**FileVault**](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/crx/current/how_to/how_to_use_the_vlttool.html) (VLT), checkout the repository to the same folder as your Git repo. Code can then be pulled down from Git & pushed up into CRX or vice versa.
2. Working within Maven or similar, build all of your code on your local file-system outside of CQ & use Felix console / CRX Package Manager to import changes into the repo.

When you export content from CRX, node data gets stored as XML files in your file-system. Each folder has a **.content.xml** file which represents its own properties, as well as folders representing its children.

In this way, you could for example create a new foo component without CRXDE by:

1. Adding a folder to your file-system, `/apps/your-project/components/content/foo`.
2. Creating a **.content.xml** file within it.

The format of the **.content.xml** would be as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" 
          xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Component"
    jcr:title="Foo"
    cq:isContainer="{Boolean}false"
    allowedParents="[*/parsys]"/>
```

- You can see above that each attribute you want to add is simply added as an attribute on the jcr:root node of the XML file.
- Multi property types are contained within square brackets, with comman-separated values (`allowedParents` above).
- Non-string data types have their type in braces before their value (`cq:isContainer` above).

Other node types also get stored as XML files, e.g. dialog nodes are stored as `dialog.xml`, cq:editConfig nodes as `_cq_editConfig.xml`, etc.